# How to display multiple elements in a new line from XML file using XQuery in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xquery

This is my XML file

```
<bookstore>
    <book category="COOKING">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="CHILDREN">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
 </book>
</bookstore>
```

and this is my Java code:

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.ddtek.xquery3.XQConnection;
import com.ddtek.xquery3.XQException;
import com.ddtek.xquery3.XQExpression;
import com.ddtek.xquery3.XQItemType;
import com.ddtek.xquery3.XQSequence;
import com.ddtek.xquery3.xqj.DDXQDataSource;

public class XQueryTester3 {

// Filename for XML document to query
private String filename;

// Data Source for querying
private DDXQDataSource dataSource;

// Connection for querying
private XQConnection conn;

public XQueryTester3(String filename) {
this.filename = "untitled1.xml";
}

public void init() throws XQException {
dataSource = new DDXQDataSource();
conn = dataSource.getConnection();
}

public String query(String queryString) throws XQException {
XQExpression expression = conn.createExpression();
expression.bindString(new QName("docName"), filename,
  conn.createAtomicType(XQItemType.XQBASETYPE_STRING));
XQSequence results = expression.executeQuery(queryString);
return results.getSequenceAsString(new Properties());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

             XQueryTester3 tester = new XQueryTester3("untitled1.xml");
             tester.init();

             final String sep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
             String queryString =
             "declare variable $docName as xs:string external;" + sep +
                            "      for $book in doc($docName)/bookstore/book " +
                            "    where $book/year =2003 " +
                            "   return " +
                            "$book/author/text()";
             System.out.println(tester.query(queryString));
           } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace(System.err);
             System.err.println(e.getMessage());
           }
}
}
```

the output will be:

```
    Erik T. Ray
```

My big problem is I would like to display the author & the title of the book, so I modified the code from

```
"declare variable $docName as xs:string external;" + sep +
                            "      for $book in doc($docName)/bookstore/book " +
                            "    where $book/year =2003 " +
                            "   return " +
                            "$book/author/text()";
             System.out.println(tester.query(queryString));
```

to be like this:

```
 "declare variable $docName as xs:string external;" + sep +
                            "      for $book in doc($docName)/bookstore/book " +
                            "    where $book/year =2003 " +
                            "   return " +
                            "$book/author/text() " +
                            "$book/title/text()";
             System.out.println(tester.query(queryString));
```

and I get an error:

```
 Unexpected token "$" beyond end of query
```

but, if I alter the code like this (adding HTML tag and curly bracket{} ):

```
   "declare variable $docName as xs:string external;" + sep +
                            "      for $book in doc($docName)/bookstore/book " +
                            "    where $book/year =2003 " +
                            "   return " +
                            "<i>{$book/author/text()} " +
                            "{$book/title/text()}</i>";
             System.out.println(tester.query(queryString));
```

I can get the output:

```
<i>Erik T. RayLearning XML</i>
```

The problem is, I don't want to have the HTML tag in my output and I want the author name & the title of the book to be in a new line..

Can anyone help me with this problems mentioned above?

How do I display multiple elements in a new line without HTML in the output?

The output should be like this:

```
Erik T. Ray

Learning XML
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `concat()`:

```
"declare variable $docName as xs:string external;" + sep +
                            "      for $book in doc($docName)/bookstore/book " +
                            "    where $book/year =2003 " +
                            "   return " +
                            "concat($book/author/text(),'&#xA;',$book/title/text())";
             System.out.println(tester.query(queryString));
```

Comment: But then, if i comment the  
     //"where $book/year =2003 " 

why do the output become like this:

    Everyday Italian 
    Giada De Laurentiis Harry Potter 
    J K. Rowling Learning XML 
    Erik T. Ray

thanks again!

Comment: i mean the result is not in a new line anymore..and would like to ask, what is this '&#xA;' ?? thanks @DevNull